# Fill an array with powers of 3

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public class Power {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int base = 3, exponent = 9;

        int[] result = new int[10];
        System.out.println(result);

        while (exponent != 0)
        {
            result * base = result;
            --exponent;
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like this code to do is be able to Multiply 1*3 to make 3, put it inside of the array, and multiply it again, and so on and so forth. Basically, it needs to output, 1 3 9 27 81 243 729 2187 6561  19683. How can I store it inside of the array, and also multiply it again?

Comment: `result * base = result;` You can't do this. The target for assignment must be on the left hand side. Did you intend to write `result = result * base`? You can also just write `result *= base`. (Although actually `result` is an array, so you can't multiply it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a result variable and continue saving it to an array:

```
int index = 0;
int[] result = new int[10];
int current = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
    result[i] = current;
    current *= 3;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.asString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that assignments need the name on the left side, and the expression on the right side; replace `result * base = result;` by `result = result * base;`.

Secondly, `result` is an *array*. You’re trying to treat it as a single number.

Thirdly, if you want to fill an array, use a `for` loop instead of what you currently have:

```
final int base = 3;

final int[] result = new int[10];
result[0] = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i - 1] * base;
}
```